# How can I load a string into a JSON object if the string contains \n?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I need to load some text from a UTF-8 data file that contains text in JSON format into a JSON object, then parse it. I do not have control over the content or format of the file and must deal with what I'm given. I also don't have control over the Python version, which is 2.7.

At least one of the values in this text file contains \n. Because of this, running the script will result in an error like this: Expecting , delimiter: line 8 column 102 (char 470)'

The file content looks like this:

```
{
"key1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"key2": "Suspendisse eu tincidunt velit. Proin mollis ligula a arcu feugiat ac imperdiet nunc sagittis. Etiam egestas fringilla tristique.\nCurabitur interdum dolor eu velit gravida et convallis purus facilisis. Aenean eu enim mi.",

"key3": "Nunc intérdum mågna nec nîbh faucibus non laoreet nisi blandit. Nunc lobortis ligula ut tellus semper in hendrerit mauris malesuada.",

"key4": "Vivamus erat turpis, fringilla id sollicitudin non, pellentesque vel lacus. Praesent placerat dapibus mauris vel hendrerit. Integer a augue leo, facilisis viverra dui. Maecenas sollicitudin adipiscing viverra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vestibulum commodo diam, vitae ultrices quam viverra eu. Proin eros sapien, scelerisque non condimentum vel, placerat at est. Ut fermentum mattis lacus, a eleifend ipsum euismod ac. Quisque mollis bibendum quam nec sollicitudin."

}
```

Relevant code:

```
def processText(stringData):
    j = json.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
    # do stuff that I can't change


dataFile = codecs.open('/path/to/file', 'r', 'utf-8')    
data = dataFile.read()
dataFile.close()
processText(data)
```

I have tried the following:

1. `json.loads(data.replace('\n','\\n')` The text file contains ~15,000
   characters, so this just causes the script to hang.
2. `json.loads("%r"%d)` where d is the variable containing the string. This results in the error 'No JSON object could be decoded' because it converts every newline in the file into \n, which is not what needs to happen.

How can I load this string into a JSON object?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  (If I do `r"""..."""` where ... is your file content, then I can `json.loads` the string you have there just fine.)

Comment: Same here. 2.7.3 is fine. I opened the file that contains the json you provided and it just works fine. Have you tried recreate a json file yourself, manually?

Comment: Do you mind posting lines 7-9 of the data file you're parsing?

Comment: When I was testing this with a heredoc (`r"""…"""`) it also worked for me.

Comment: As a side note,when opening text files make sure you are in universal mode, so use 'rU' not just 'r' as the mode parameter. It makes sure the new line characters are consistent across OS's

Comment: Just corroborating everyone else here... I'm using 2.7.3 and can't reproduce this. It loads just fine.

Comment: Yep, same here. Works on 2.7.2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

`json` string may contain `\n` (two characters). So if you see in a file `\n`; it is ok.

Valid json (as seen in a file (not Python source code)):

```
["line\nanother"]
```

Invalid:

```
["line
another"]
```

The confusion might arise if you include the file content as a Python string **literal**. In this case `\n` is also interpreted by Python before it gets to `json` parser. To avoid it, use `r''` literals:

```
json_text = r'["line\nanother"]'
print(json_text) # -> ["line\nanother"]
d = json.loads(json_text)
```

If you read json from a file; you don't need to do anything (`\n` are just another two bytes; you'll get them as is):

```
with open(filename) as file: # don't need `codecs` if file is in utf-8
    d = json.load(file)
    # analog of: d = json.loads(file.read())
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `strict=False` in `json.loads()`:

```py
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8') 
body = json.loads(body_unicode,strict=False)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).